# JupyterLab 3.0.16: Exporting HTML results on "Blocking request with no referer" and "403 Blocking request from unknown origin"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am having what seems to be a perennial problem with JupyterLab users but when applying the solutions that have worked with others, I am not getting positive results.

This problem is new, only emerging over the past few weeks.

This problem is occurring only with JupyterLab (not Jupyter Notebook) for ...

- Operating System: macOS-11.4-x86_64-i386-64bit
- Miniconda Build: 4.10.1
- Python Version: 3.8.10
- Browsers:

  - Safari for MacOS 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)
  - Chrome for MacOS 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Jupyter Suite Versions:

  - jupyter                       1.0.0
  - jupyter-client                6.1.12
  - jupyter-console               6.4.0
  - jupyter-core                  4.7.1
  - jupyter-server                1.8.0
  - jupyterlab                    3.0.16
  - jupyterlab-pygments           0.1.2
  - jupyterlab-server             2.5.2
  - jupyterlab-widgets            1.0.0

Problem:

When working with a *locally*-run JupyterLab (i.e., using a URL of 128.0.0.1:8888, or localhost:8888), when Exporting a IPYNB notebook to HTML, txt or other format, I get the following two errors:

```
[W 2021-05-27 14:50:15.795 ServerApp] Blocking request with no referer
[W 2021-05-27 14:50:15.795 ServerApp] 403 GET /nbconvert/html/Untitled.ipynb?download=true (::1): Blocking request from unknown origin
```

However, when using the same IPYNB notebook (even one simply consisting of a single cell saying *print("hello")*, in a basic Jupyter *Notebook* session the exports function satisfactorily and create nice viewable HTML and PDF files.

I have search across solution resources and the closet thing I've seen for guidance has been to add the change two lines in the jupyter configuration files as so:

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin=''
c.NotebookApp.allow_remote_access = True
```

I have tried this on more than one fresh install of Minconda and this does not yield favorable results.  (Some of these recommendations are coming for users of JupyterHub, not JupyterLab).

I have a "gist" from a sample JupyterLab session available showing both

- the debug log of the specific problem if a notebook with the single cell containing "print('Hello')"
- the output of the jupyter troubleshoot command showing the configuration of my miniconda/python/jupyter setup.

https://gist.github.com/wjcapehart/a6145ae8e7e1f967bab7412fd118c455
(my username is replaced with ${HOME} in the Gist files.)

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Cheers and Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 2):

Issue [jupyterlab #7539](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7539) may be related. In the meantime, you might want to try Firefox as a workaround. It seems that Chrome (and probably Safari and others) are not a sending `Referer` header, and that is causing the problem.

I am experiencing the same problem with a JupyterLab instance with a domain (unlike your local install). And I can confirm that Firefox works.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `c.ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf = True` in `jupyter_server_config.py` fixed the errors "Blocking request from unknown origin" and "Blocking request with no referer" when using Safari with a localhost instance of jupyter-lab (3.1.7).

To determine where jupyter config files are located use the command

```
$ jupyter-lab --paths
```

Then generate a default config which has all default values commented out

```
$ jupyter-lab server --generate-config
```

Add the config change (note the comment regarding the security warning)

```
c.ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf = True
```

Verify the current config.

```
$ jupyter-lab --show-config
```

Hopefully this helps others.

Comment: Note that there is also a command-line option for Jupyter for this, like so `jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.extra_static_paths="$PWD"/ --notebook-dir "$PWD" --NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True``